# What effect does being slowed have on overland movement in D&D 4e

Tags: dnd-4e, dungeons-and-dragons, movement

On page 336 of Heroes of the Fallen Lands it states that if a character tries to carry 20 times their strength score then they are slowed.

I know during combat being slowed means you can only move two squares. The question I have is how does being slowed affect overland movement?

Answer (score 3):

**10 miles per day,

1 mile per hour,

100ft. per minute.**

I'd point you the the answer to [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/4926/what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-overland-speed-in-dd4e) question which extrapolates the *1 unit of speed = 5 miles per day* ratio.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that it reduces your speed by the same proportion. If your base speed is 6 sqrs and your now moving 2sqrs then you're moving at 1/3 speed. Looking at this questions about **[What is the best way to determine Overland Speed in D&D4e?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/4926/2788)** there are various methods:

- Using Iszis you move at 10 mi/day or 1 MPH or 100 ft/min.
- Using my method we still divide *combat* speed by 6, to get *overland* speed in Mi/day so your speed is going to be 2 sqrs/6 = 0.3 sqrs/round. That's because your *6 times slower when moving overland* than in combat. To get it into mi/day then you multiply your combat speed by 2, giving you 4 Mi/day

Comment: Surely using Iszi's figures would lead to a result of 10 miles a day (1 mph for 10 hours march). Those figures would also give 100 ft/min (which is the same as combat speed, given 2 squares/round, which is 10ft/round, and a round as six seconds).

Comment: Ah I'm getting confused with units and stuff.