# How to make my mount travel more in one day

Tags: dnd-4e, magic-items, mount

I have a Celestial Charger (Adventures Valt pag. 11) for a mount, it can travel 40 miles in a day.

Is there a way to make it travel further?

I don´t need anything to use during combat. The mount speed can remain the same. I just need it to travel more in one day.

Comment: What is the rest of your party using that you're the slowest?

Comment: Lets not forget that 4e is about heroic characters. PHB has an entry showing that Per Day miles is 5 x your Speed. See this answer. http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/4928/3529  So a regular lvl 1 character in heavy armor could still manage 25 miles in a day.

Comment: This is actually for a player that likes to be the "lonely wolf" of our group. He want to have the horse of Gandalf, basically.

Comment: You want to increase how far the mount travels in a day without increasing its speed... So, you'd drop behind the party for most of the day, but catch up with them just after they've finished setting up the tents and are sitting down to dinner? Nice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You have two item-related options**

The first is a mount item that will increase your speed by 1. This will translate into 5 more miles traveled each day.

> **Horseshoes of Speed** Lvl 3 Uncommon
>
> Mount        680 gp
> **Property:** The mount’s speed increases by 1 square for all movement modes.

and

> **Skystrider Horseshoes** Lvl 18 Uncommon
>
> Mount        85,000 gp
> **Property:** The mount gains a fly speed equal to its land speed.

Which won't increase your speed, but by flying you can move in a direct straight line vs. having to go around terrain like mountains, swamps, deep rivers etc.

**And as as Waxeagle pointed out some other alternatives:**

**Light Step Feat: Elf Prereq**

Will add +1 to the travel rates (hours and daily) for you and your allies.

**Shadow Walk Ritual**

Will multiply you and your allies travel speed by 5.

Comment: If a mount is a vehicle, which it probably isn't, then the Enhance Vessel ritual (EPG) would help. Also, the Find the Path ritual increases the distance 'you' can travel to a specific direction by 10 miles per day.